# Oracle Apex Data Load

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

After creating some pages using Apex 5.1's Data Load Wizard, would it be possible via the Page Designer to somewhere hack into the data and add in 2 extra column data. I am attempting to add the following columns (1) Updater (2) Update date/time. I was able to do the same thing with an Interactive Grid page by adding PL/SQL code to the 'Save' Page Processing section but could not do the same for the Data Load Pages.

I have a five attribute table, 2 of which (Updater, Update date/time) are hidden to the APEX app user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a Data Load **Transformation Rule**. You can add this by editing the Data Load Definition via Shared Components. You specify the column, and you can specify a Rule Type of **PLSQL Expression** and set the expression to whatever you want, e.g. SYSDATE.

Another option is to add a trigger to the table to set those columns.

Comment: Tried out the transformation rule and it's all good! Thank you.

Comment: Jeffrey, would you have a suggestion with regards to as to how a record be designated as a new entry or just an edit of an existing one at the transformation timing?

Comment: That's a tricky one. I can find nothing in Apex's Dataload feature that supports that out of the box. A trigger can detect an insert vs update but you'd need some way of isolating the data load transaction from other transactions that might be running concurrently.

Comment: I tried this but it is not adding that column’s data is the column is not mapped